# DirectX Converting Pixel World Position to Shadow Map Position Gives Weird, Tiled Results

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

I've been trying for some time now to get a screen-space pixel (provided by a deferred HLSL shader) to convert to light space.  The results have been surprising to me as my light rendering seems to be tiling the depth buffer.

Importantly, the scene camera (or eye) and the light being rendered from start in the same position.

First, I extract the world position of the pixel using the code below:

```
float3 eye = Eye;
float4 position = {
    IN.texCoord.x * 2 - 1,
    (1 - IN.texCoord.y) * 2 - 1,
    zbuffer.r,
    1
};
float4 hposition = mul(position, EyeViewProjectionInverse);
position = float4(hposition.xyz / hposition.w, hposition.w);
float3 eyeDirection = normalize(eye - position.xyz);
```

The result seems to be correct as rendering the XYZ position as RGB respectively yields this (apparently correct) result:

[image: Correctly rendered XYZ]

The red component seems to be correctly outputting X as it moves to the right, and blue shows Z moving forward.  The Y factor also looks correct as the ground is slightly below the Y axis.

Next (and to be sure I'm not going crazy), I decided to output the original depth buffer.  Normally I keep the depth buffer in a Texture2D called `DepthMap` passed to the shader as input.  In this case, however, I try to undo the pixel transformation by offsetting it back into the proper position and multiplying it by the eye's view-projection matrix:

```
float4 cpos = mul(position, EyeViewProjection);
cpos.xyz = cpos.xyz / cpos.w;
cpos.x = cpos.x * 0.5f + 0.5f;
cpos.y = 1 - (cpos.y * 0.5f + 0.5f);
float camera_depth = pow(DepthMap.Sample(Sampler, cpos.xy).r, 100); // Power 100 just to visualize the map since scales are really tiny
return float4(camera_depth, camera_depth, camera_depth, 1);
```

This yields a correct looking result as well (though I'm not 100% sure about the Z value).  Also note that I've made the results exponential to better visualize the depth information (this is not done when attempting live comparisons):

[image: Reinterpreting XYZ back to ZBuffer space]

So theoretically, I can use the same code to convert that pixel world position to light space by multiplying by the light's view-projection matrix.  Correct?  Here's what I tried:

```
float4 lpos = mul(position, ShadowLightViewProjection[0]);
lpos.xyz = lpos.xyz / lpos.w;
lpos.x = lpos.x * 0.5f + 0.5f;
lpos.y = 1 - (lpos.y * 0.5f + 0.5f);
float shadow_map_depth = pow(ShadowLightMap[0].Sample(Sampler, lpos.xy).r, 100); // Power 100 just to visualize the map since scales are really tiny
return float4(shadow_map_depth, shadow_map_depth, shadow_map_depth, 1);
```

And here's the result:

[image: Broken light space]

And another to show better how it's mapping to the world:

[image: Broken light space #2]

I don't understand what is going on here.  It seems it might have something to do with the projection matrix, but I'm not that good with math to know for sure what is happening.  It's definitely not the width/height of the light map as I've tried multiple map sizes and the projection matrix is calculated using FOV and aspect ratios never inputing width/height ever.

Finally, here's some C++ code showing how my perspective matrix (used for both eye and light) is calculated:

```
    const auto ys = std::tan((T)1.57079632679f - (fov / (T)2.0));
    const auto xs = ys / aspect;
    const auto& zf = view_far;
    const auto& zn = view_near;
    const auto zfn = zf - zn;

    row1(xs, 0, 0, 0);
    row2(0, ys, 0, 0);
    row3(0, 0, zf / zfn, 1);
    row4(0, 0, -zn * zf / zfn, 0);
    return *this;
```

I'm completely at a loss here.  Any guidance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT** - I also forgot to mention that the tiled image is upside down as if the y flip broke it.  That's strange to me as it's required to get it back to eye texture space correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I did some tweaking and fixed things here and there.  Ultimately, my biggest issue was an unexpectedly transposed matrix.  It's a bit complicated as to how the matrix got transposed, but that's why things were flipped.  I also changed to D32 depth buffers (though I'm not sure that helped any) and made sure that any positions divided by their W affected all component (including W).

So code like this: `hposition.xyz = hposition.xyz / hposition.w`
became this: `hposition = hposition / hposition.w`

After all this tweaking, it's starting to look more like a shadow map.

Oh and the transposed matrix was the ViewProjection of the light.